# animate/flash circle drawn with android canvas

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-view

I have a custom view. I override the onDraw method to draw a filled circle, among other things. I want the circle to flash between red and blue, the interval can be 100 milliseconds. How would I accomplish such animation? So far I have

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    this.mFilledPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, mFilledPaint);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int color = Color.BLUE;
postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        color = (color == Color.BLUE) ? Color.Black : Color.BLUE;
        invalidate();
        postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
}, 100);

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    this.mFilledPaint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, mFilledPaint);
}
```

Call the post delayed in the constructor or nay other function you feel relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where in my method would your snippet go? will you please rewrite my `onDraw` to include your snippet? I play around with it, nothing works. I even changed 100 to 1000